What tv show (movie)? Girl unknowingly subject of photographer's work
This may be a tough one... but it's driving me crazy. I think it's from a tv show but it might be a movie. Basically this is what I remember:
It's a scene at an art gallery or art showcase, and the main female character is the subject of a male character's photography series  (I believe several large photos, and I believe the girl did not know the photos were going to be showcased). I think then another male character (protective or romantic interest) buys the photos, either because he doesn't like the idea of everyone seeing them displayed or because he wants them because of his infatuation (I believe it's the former though).
Ringing any bells? I think the two males characters don't know each other at this point. And I think the female character confronts the photographer in her shock at being on display, but the photographer tells her the photos were already sold (to male #2). The photos were just of her face, emotions, possibly black and white.
I know this is a long shot, but I thought it was from one show and it wasn't... so now I can't figure it out :(
I must've seen it within the last few years I think. Probably something fairly new, but definitely nothing this year.

There is a scene like you describe in the TV series "Pan Am", where the blond younger sister character had posed for a New York photographer, with the scene playing out as described.

Do you remember which episode it was, by any chance?

Pan Am S01E12 synopsis - ...and Laura is shocked to discover that the Life Magazine photographer, Graham, sold the nude photos he took of her to a gallery, where they are on display.
